# Scaling a single character font to its parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, scaling

I am trying to fit a single character font-size to its parent div. is it possible?

Maybe it's a [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)
by @[Francesca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178820/francesca) duplicate?

But my context is a **Single Character** so maybe it is possible but font can be normal font-family or iconic font like font-awesome.

I appreciate a fiddle work

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial
}

.box1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

.box2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: calc(3vw + 3vh);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box1">x</div>
<button class="box1">x</button>
<div class="box2"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></div>
<button class="box2"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
```

Comment: what you want to do..? Can you share any screenshot for this.?

Comment: parent div have a background image & I want a character fit over them like x

Comment: do you want character fit or character center of its div..?

Comment: I want to fit it

Answer (score 0):

I have try it with some js code but its depend on parents width or height.

```js
 var fontSize = parseInt($(".box1").height())+"px";
 $(".box1").css('font-size', fontSize);
 
  var fontSize = parseInt($(".box2").height())+"px";
 $(".box2").css('font-size', fontSize);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Arial
}

.box1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;  
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.box2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  text-align:center;  
}
.box2 i {
  display: block;
  line-height: 97%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box1">x</div>
<button class="box1">x</button>
<div class="box2"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></div>
<button class="box2"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
```

Comment: thanks, I also tried it with padding: 0px; can we exact fit ?, i mean no padding